# Is there a way to make a cross-origin request using perl dancer?

Tags: javascript, perl, cross-domain, cors, dancer

I'm trying to get a response from a service from another domain > "http://another.domain.com/service/" which uses CORS module, cross-origin headers are already existing.
The response can already be obtained in JS using

```
return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

But I'm try to make this possible within a dancer 'get' route.

Is this possible? Is making the request within Dancer better?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the pieces fit together. The same-origin policy only applies to the browser. Backend processes can make cross-domain requests without any restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Your question didn't make sense 100% as mentioned by the other commenters.

However if you're trying to grant cross-origin access in a Dancer route, as mentioned by part of your question, this is how you do it:

```
get '...' => sub {
  ...
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*');
  ...
  };
```